# Links to other Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, links

This may be question of understanding, rather than obtaining a solution. I have a Google Spreadsheet sheet embedded in a (public) word press website page. It contains columns with external hyperlinks and these work fine to anyone accessing the page. It also contains a column with a link to a specific sheet in a *different* spreadsheet on the same account and drive. However, this link does not work without a Google account (I know). I could put all the data on the linked sheet into a separately embedded sheet (without any link) and I assume this would be accessible without a Google account. But this is time and space consuming and is basically a non-starter. So why is this Google account requirement there? Just to have everyone have a Google account? Is there a workaround, because large numbers of potentials users will be put off by this.

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. My first thought (maybe wrong) is that the "Google Account" is a red-herring. I think "permissions" might be the issue: you said it was _a link to a specific sheet in a different spreadsheet on the same account and drive_.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but that specific sheet does not sound as though it is `published to web`; rather it is simply a link to that spreadsheet - so what are the sharing permissions on that specific sheet and that specific spreadsheet?

Comment: Just on a tangent, the title of your question is "Links to other Google Sheets"  but this doesn't really reflect the substance or circumstances of the question.

Comment: Hands up - and thank you Tedinoz. I can see immediately it is a naive newbie mistake, which i shall correct by changing the publishings and permissions. (The tangential mis-titling followed as a sort of unknown unknown from it!) Thanks again.